# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idPatient' of undefined (after press F5)

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idPatient' of undefined (after press F5)

```
export default function LabPaymentCheck() {
    
      const params = useParams();
      const name = params.name;
    
      const { patientByID, dataloading, testByID } = useTracker(() => {
        Meteor.subscribe("patientsInfo");
        const handle = Meteor.subscribe("patientsTestsChecked");
        const dataloading = handle.ready();
        const testByID = patientsTestsCheckedCollection.findOne({
          _id: name,
        });
        const patientByID = patientsInfoCollection.findOne({
          _id: testByID.idPatient,
        });
        return { dataloading, testByID, patientByID };
      }, [name]);
    
     return (...)
    }
```

Comment: Hi it look like your calling this function not in sequence maybe this function will call after F5 before main function. So you need to check this manually

Comment: In the first render return the data correctly, after I press F5, throw that error.

Comment: Make a snippet and update all code so we can debug what is issue

Comment: Add condition if(TestId.id) { your code here } It might be possible that no patients with that name in collection.